# Easy way to toggle dns to auto for public WiFi networks

Tags: windows-10, dns, script, wifi-configuration

I normally set my windows 10  dns to Google's public dns. This works great except for public WiFi access with captive portals where I need to manually find my wifi adapter's TCP IP properties and change the DNS settings to auto.

But then I need to remember to return them to Google dns etc.

Is there a faster way to do this? Maybe an app or script that allows me to just double click something to do the necessary toggling?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The command line to change the DNS servers for a Windows machine is something:

```
netsh int ip set dns name = "Local Area Connection" source = static addr = x.x.x.x
```

You can prepare two batch files as you need.